# Print all possible combinations of an array of arrays

Tags: arrays, perl

I want to take three files that each contain 80 or more lines of text and print all possible combinations of those three files.

For the sake of clarity, let's assume that

#### File1 contains

```
1
2
3
```

#### File2 contains

```
4
5
6
```

#### File3 contains

```
7
8
9
```

If I wanted to print only those combinations then there are many answers that I could use. However, as the files contain more lines that I care type manually into the Perl script. I am building an array from each file, then I build an array ref of those arrays. Finally I am attempting to use [`List::Permutor`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Permutor) to print the combinations.

The problem I am getting is that I am printing out the memory references, and I cannot figure out how to dereference the arrays inside of the `List::Permutor` call.

#### Perl code

```perl
use List::Permutor;
use warnings;

open (FILE, app_txt);
chomp (@app = (<FILE>));
close (FILE);

open (FILE, att1_txt);
chomp (@att1 = (<FILE>));
close (FILE);

open (FILE, att2_txt);
chomp (@att2 = (<FILE>));
close (FILE);

my $permutor = List::Permutor->new( \@app, \@att1, \@att2);

while ( my @permutation = $permutor->next() ) {
    print "@permutation\n";
}
```

Comment: show what output you want for your 1,2,3 / 4,5,6 / 7,8,9 example please, just to clarify what you want

Comment: *"I am attempting to use List::Permutor to print the combinations"* `List::Permutor` is for generating *permutations*. If you want *combinations* then you need a different module, perhaps [Math::Combinatorics](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Combinatorics)

Comment: You started well with *"For the sake of clarity, let's assume that  File1 contains..."* but you never refer to that data again so there is no clarity! Please explain what you need in terms of that simplified data; then we will be able to help you

Answer (score 2):

I wrote [Set::CrossProduct](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Set::CrossProduct) for this purpose.

Comment: Wow, this is literally what I wanted to do. Ill just save that one for next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you want.

Note that all the provided output of the snippets below are for the following inputs:

```
my @app  = ( 1, 2, 3 );
my @att1 = ( 4, 5, 6 );
my @att2 = ( 7, 8, 9 );
```

---

If you want permutations of the arrays, your code works as-is.

```
use List::Permutor qw( );

my $permutor = List::Permutor->new( \@app, \@att1, \@att2);
while ( my @permutation = $permutor->next() ) {
   say join ", ", map { "[@$_]" } @permutation;
}
```

Output:

```
[1 2 3], [4 5 6], [7 8 9]
[1 2 3], [7 8 9], [4 5 6]
[4 5 6], [1 2 3], [7 8 9]
[4 5 6], [7 8 9], [1 2 3]
[7 8 9], [1 2 3], [4 5 6]
[7 8 9], [4 5 6], [1 2 3]
```

---

If you want permutations of the contents of the arrays (regardless of the array from which a string originated), then you just need to create a list from the contents of the arrays.

```
use List::Permutor qw( );

my $permutor = List::Permutor->new( @app, @att1, @att2 );
while ( my @permutation = $permutor->next() ) {
   say "@permutation";
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 8 7 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 9 7 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 9 8 7
1 2 3 4 5 7 6 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 7 6 9 8
1 2 3 4 5 7 8 6 9
1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 6
...
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Keep in mind that P(80) is 100,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 times the number of atoms in the observable universe.

---

If you want all possible sets of a single element from each array, then you can use the following:

```
for my $app (@app) {
for my $att1 (@att1) {
for my $att2 (@att2) {
   say "$app $att1 $att2";
}}}
```

or

```
use Algorithm::Loops qw( NestedLoops );

my $iter = NestedLoops([ \@app, \@att1, \@att2 ]);
while ( my ($app, $att1, $att2) = $iter->() ) {
   say "$app $att1 $att2";
}
```

Output:

```
1 4 7
1 4 8
1 4 9
1 5 7
1 5 8
1 5 9
1 6 7
1 6 8
1 6 9
2 4 7
...
3 6 9
```

Comment: Aren't there 492,960 ways to permutate 80 items? ie 80 * 79 * 78.  And if he has 3 files with "around 80+ items each", then isn't it 240 items being permutated?

Comment: @Marty, No, there are P(80,80) = 80! = 80*79*78*77*76*..*1 = more than 7e118 ways to permute 80 items. /// He didn't say that each file had 80 items. /// But you bring up a third interpretation, which I've added to my answer. (Though under that interpretation, there would be P(80,1)*P(80,1)*P(80,1)=80*80*80=512,000 results rather than 492,960  when there are 80 items in each file.)

Comment: Of course.  For some reason I've focused on there being 3 files and mixed it up with choosing 3 items from the collection.  Either way, I don't think the questioner will be printing them all out anytime soon.  ;-)

Comment: Thank you everyone who has commented since I posted this question last night. To further clarify I would like the arrays to stay in that order (I just realized I didnt specify that earlier), but with the current code it prints the memory address locations, not the contents of the arrays. I am going to try some of the suggested code and will let you know if it works for me.

Comment: That doesn't clarify anything. Please provide the output you desire.

Comment: So the last option is the closest to what I am looking for, though I had to change say to print as I got a weird declaration error. At the moment it is printing as one column with some weird concatenation of the words. I can probably puzzle out the formatting, so thank you.

Comment: Because many of you are wondering why I am doing this, I am putting together a source for a generator, so one line would be randomly picked and three attributes (one from each file) will be displayed. The number of lines in some of the files are actually closer to 200, though once I have it in text format obviously I wont have to recalculate it each time.

Comment: You need to add `use feature qw( say );` to use `say`. Basics such as those, `use strict;` and `use warnings;` were omitted for brevity.

Comment: I just did it with print, no reason to do say if I have to enable the function. Only problem now is that the strings in the first file have spaces and special characters so if I chomp it the output is funny. If I dont chomp it, the newline remains a problem. So, I need to figure out how to clean it up, after it has gone through iterations/permutations but before the print command.

Comment: There are no permutations in what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my last issue with formatting, by cheating. I just edited the source files and removed all the \r and \n.

Final code:

```
use Algorithm::Loops qw( NestedLoops );
use warnings;

open (FILE, app_txt);
 ($app = (<FILE>));
close (FILE);
my @app = split /,/, $app;

open (FILE, att1_txt);
 ($att1 = (<FILE>));
close (FILE);
my @att1 = split /,/, $att1;

open (FILE, att2_txt);
 ($att2 = (<FILE>));
close (FILE);
my @att2= split /,/, $att2;

my $iter = NestedLoops([ \@app, \@att1, \@att2 ]);
while ( my ($app, $att1, $att2) = $iter->() ) {
    open (my $fh, '>', 'test');
    print  $fh "$app $att1 $att2\n";
    close $fh;
}

print "done\n";
```